# Added an Image"A". Want to Display the image in div"A" , div"B" and div"C". How?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

-
I am making an order form with a review page.
when order form is fully filled, then it automatically send each data to
each div on the review page. This is what I want.

I know I can copy a data into another div by using javascript like

```
<script>
    function filling() {
        var something = $('#input').val();
        document.getElementById("divbox").innerHTML = something;
    }
</script>
```

but when it's not a data that can be displayed with text(for example, an image or a video), then how can I send the data into another div?

- Thanks to digging really hard the internet, I found an open source contact form with the image attachment function. what's cool about this is, when I attach an image, it resizes and show to client-side.

(http://webreflection.blogspot.kr/2010/12/100-client-side-image-resizing.html)

So, I am modifying this into an order form, and I want, when a client attach an image, it shows to the client the resized version of it, and it also shows in the div on review page.

How can I do this? 
`getElementbyClassName` or Name did not work because of the "auto resizing script"

-
I'm sorry for my english being to poor. and thank you for your patient to have read this last line. Have a nice day.

Comment: What's `the auto resizing` script?

Comment: @hina10531
here. 
(http://webreflection.blogspot.kr/2010/12/100-client-side-image-resizing.html)
it's um. When I attach an image file, it resizes and show right under the [file browse] button. also works on server too.

Comment: So that people can check if the attached is right file or not by looking at the resized image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few ways:

```
<script>
    function filling() {
        var something = $('#source').html(); // Can be some element, like another DIV
        $("#divbox").append(something);
    }
</script>
```

Depending on what you need, can also use `clone()` (https://api.jquery.com/clone/):

```
function filling(){
    $("#source").clone().append("#divbox");
}
```

Comment: oh my god thank you so much. I'll try this right away!!! thank you so much. . . it was really hard for me to swin into this programming thing. I am a painter. so . . . it's like really... for me it's harder than speaking in English beside my mother language. thank you so much.